# Launch android app activity from web link that both starts and ends in a specific way

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-networking

Is there a way to launch a web link with an application activity where the web link starts and ends in a specific manner?

I want to launch an activity if a user clicks on a web link to a particular website, for example that has been shared on facebook or via email, and that starts with the website address but only if it ends with "story.html". So for example `http://www.storyofmathematics.com/` would not open the app but `http://www.storyofmathematics.com/story.html` would

Comment: You can do that by taking the String/Link and checking if it matches "your specific string" or checking as whatever you want using [patterns](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Is it possible to do that from within the intent filter? So the option to launch the link with the app would only appear if it was a match? Such as <intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="**REGEX**"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>

Comment: Firs of all you have to take the string. Parse it, split it or filterit as you want using `patters (regex)`. Check if it matches your need and then do with that whatever you want

Comment: Right ok. I'll have a play around and if I find a decent solution I'll post it up here. Thanks

Comment: @hrskrs I've found a pretty tidy way of doing it - see answer

Comment: you can play with regex now depending on what do you want to achieve. Glad if i helped you. Don't forget to upvote helpful answers/comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding the activity to the manifest with the appropriate intent filter

```
    <activity
        android:name=".WebActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="www.storyofmathematics.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="storyofmathematics.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then by running a regex from within the activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class WebActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (intent.getDataString().matches(
                "http:\\/\\/((www.)?)storyofmathematics.com\\/.*story.html")) {
            // is match - do stuff
        } else {
            // is not match - do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```